# Error powershell does not contain a method named save

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I copy an old excel file (excel 97) from one location to another location using PowerShell. It worked until last Sunday and it got error:

> "error in method invocation failed (system.IO.file into) ..does not contain a method named "saved""
>
> error is access to the path denied

Do you know what I need to do with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account you are using to run this code still holds the permission to the destination path.

**Note:Post the code here with error messages**